# Puedo hacer esto en python (django)?

Tags: python, django

estoy en un modelo y quiero obtener un atributo del modelo, pero tengo el atributo como cadena.

lo correcto seria hacer esto:
`self.nombre`

pero tengo esto:
`text = "nombre"`

como hago para acceder al atributo de con lo que tengo

Comment: Puedes usar la funcions getattr(object, name): object es el objeto y name es el nombre de la propiedad en tu caso es el que esta guardado en la variable text

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió :D

Comment: Entonces te dejare una breve descripción de estas funciones peculiares de python :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función getattr, es una de las famosas funciónes built-in de python, estas nos ayudan principalmente para cosas de instrospeción y metaprogramción.

El nombre de la función en español se puede traducir como obtener atributo, lo cual es bastante descripctibo de lo que hace.

Esta función recibe dos parametros un objeto, que será una instancia de alguna clase y un string, que representa el nombre del atributo

Especificamente esta función nos devolvere el valor del atributo de un determinado objeto, si algun dado caso nostros pasamos un atributo que no existe en el objeto se lanza una exepción de tipo AttributeError. Obtenemos el mismo resultado usando el acceso del punto `obj.attr`.

Casos utiles de esta función, es por ejemplo si quisieramos preguntarle al usuario por pantalla que atributo quiere obtener:

Ejemplo:

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

person = Person('Jorge', 18)
attr = input('Que atributo desea recuperar')

print(getattr(person, attr)) #=> Nos devolvera el valor del atributo que el usuario escojio, o una excepción
```

Puedes encontrar un poco mas de información aquí: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075190/what-is-getattr-exactly-and-how-do-i-use-it